# ColdFusion Options removed after selecting option

Tags: coldfusion

I'm having trouble with my ColdFusion code. I'm trying to create a simple HTML select form using cfloop to populate the options. it works, and when you select an option, it pulls that option from the db. but once you do that, the only option available is the option previously selected. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <!--- Query the DataBase --->
<cfparam name="url.colors" default="">
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "colordb")>
    <cfset url.colordb = form.colordb>
</cfif>
<cfquery datasource="bentest" name="colors">
    SELECT *
    FROM color_codes
    <cfif structKeyExists(url,"colordb") and isNumeric(url.colordb)>
        WHERE id=#url.colordb#
    </cfif>
</cfquery>
<!--- Add Selector for user to select a color --->
<div class="selector">
    <cfoutput>
        <form action="?contentId=colorPickdb" name="clr" method="post" class="clr">
            <select class="clr" name="colordb" onChange="submit();">
                <option selected>Select A Color!</option>
                <cfloop query="colors">
                    <option value="#colors.id#">#colors.color#</option>
                </cfloop>   
            </select>
        </form>
    </cfoutput>
</div>
<div class="dump">
    <!--- Output results of Query --->
    <p><cfif structKeyExists(form, "colordb")>
        <cfoutput query="colors">
            #colors.color# <br>
            #colors.hexvalue# <br><br>
        </cfoutput>
        </cfif>
        <br>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: The where clause `WHERE id=#url.colordb#` is active once you select an options and the page submits, so only that color is selected from the DB.

Comment: Nothing to do with the original question, but ... never use raw client supplied values in sql like this `WHERE id=#url.colordb#`. Always use cfqueryparam to help protect against sql injection and boost performance.

Comment: Not related to your question, but using the onChange method of a drop down to submit a form often causes unintentional and annoying form submissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use query of query here.

```
<!--- Query the DataBase --->
<cfparam name="url.colors" default="">
<cfquery datasource="bentest" name="colors">
    SELECT *
    FROM color_codes
</cfquery>
<!--- Add Selector for user to select a color --->
<div class="selector">
    <cfoutput>
        <form action="?contentId=colorPickdb" name="clr" method="post" class="clr">
            <select class="clr" name="colordb" onChange="submit();">
                <option selected>Select A Color!</option>
                <cfloop query="colors">
                    <option value="#colors.id#">#colors.color#</option>
                </cfloop>   
            </select>
        </form>
    </cfoutput>
</div>
<div class="dump">
    <!--- Output results of Query --->
    <p>
        <cfif structKeyExists(form, "colordb")>
            <cfquery dbtype="query" name="colorSelected">
                SELECT *
                FROM colors
                WHERE id=#form.colordb#
            </cfquery>
            <cfoutput query="colorSelected">
                #colorSelected.color# <br>
                #colorSelected.hexvalue# <br><br>
            </cfoutput>
        </cfif>
        <br>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course production code should not be using `SELECT *` and should be using `<cfqueryparam>`